# Growth rate netlogo

Tags: installation, types, netlogo, patch

How can I, in the setup stage, add a growth rate between 2 type of agents I have?
In other words, I have type 0 and type 1 of patches.
I want set in the setup a slider in which I can decide the growth rate percentage between type 0 and type 1.

```
globals[]


;patches attributes
patches-own  [
  id
  ptype
  growth
]

;turtles attributes
turtles-own [
  ttype
  previous-id
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ;set patch
  ask patches[
    set pcolor white
    set ptype 0
    set growth (ptype 0) + (ptype 1 * Per-Patches1 / 100) (here the problem)
  ]
```

Thank you!

I can't find the code

Answer (score 2):

You only have a single turtles-own variable called `ptype`. That `ptype` is set to 0. There is no such thing as a variable called `ptype 0` or a variable called `ptype 1` so using that in a calculation will evidently give you errors. More specifically, what you wrote in your last line of code comes down to:

```
set growth (0 0) + (0 1 * Per-Patches1 / 100)
```

Your problem is not the slider, but rather the fact that you don't seem to define your growth rate and your different patch types well.
After you have divided the patches in two groups, you can let them choose their growth depending on which `ptype` they have using an `ifelse` function.

```
ask patches [ 
  (ifelse
    ptype = 0 [set growth growth-input ] 
    ptype = 1 [set growth growth-input * modifier-from-slider ]
  )
]
```

I here added the `ifelse` function with round brackets, since this one lets you enter multiple conditions. The shorter way to write it would be the following, but I think that in this case it is good to specifically differentiate between the ptypes, just so that you see more clearly what is happening.

```
ask patches [ ifelse ptype = 0 [set growth growth-input ] [set growth growth-input * modifier-from-slider ] ]
```